# Is it correct to say "give me 100 bamboo segments and I will turn them into a bamboo with 100 nodes"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

According to my study, the part between 2 nodes of a bamboo is called "**internode**". But there is no such word in dictionaries.

**What do you say that part in everyday English?**

Can we call it "**a bamboo segment**"?

For example, a farmer had to find a bamboo with 100 nodes but he couldn't find it. So, he cried and a good spirit appeared and the good spirit said:

"**give me 100 bamboo segments and I will turn them into a bamboo with 100 nodes**"

**Can the good spirit say that in everyday English?**

or does he have to say "**give me 100 bamboo internodes and I will turn them into a bamboo with 100 nodes**"?

Comment: an average English speaker would not know what bamboo "segments" or "nodes" or "internodes" are. You would have to define/explain whichever terms you choose.

Comment: Do you mean that given one bamboo trunk with 100 nodes, the 'good spirit' can grow another 100 plants, each with 100 nodes?

Comment: @WeatherVane, no, I mean the spirit will join 100 internodes together to form a bamboo with 100 nodes

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a specific word for this in everyday English.  But "segment" would probably be understood.

Culm, node and internode are technical biological terms.  Node has a general meaning, so  might be understood.

So I'd say "give me 100 pieces of bamboo and I'll make a bamboo trunk with 100 segments.